# Error says "Mutating a managed object after it has been removed from its context" when deleting child level data in CoreData

Tags: ios, core-data, swiftui

There two entities `Parent` and `Child`, which is one to many relationship. One Parent and many Child.

In a `ChildView`, I will get current `Child` level data's `Parent` by `self.child.parent`. But error occurs when update `Parent` in the following code and the error line has been pointed.

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

struct ChildView: View {

    var child: Child

    @ObservedObject private var db = CoreDataDB<Child>

    var body: some View {
        VStack {

            Button(action: { 
                CoreData.stack.context.delete(self.child)
                self.update()
            }) {
                Text("delete this child data")
            }
        }

    }

    func update() {

        let predicate: NSPredicate? = NSPredicate(format: "parent = %@", self.child.parent) // predicate by current child's parent 
        let children = self.db.loadDB(predicate: predicate)

        if children.count != 0 {
            children.first!.parent.updateCount(count: children.first!.parent.count) <-- Error occurs in this line when the button tapped every time
        }
    }

}
```

> [error] error: Mutating a managed object 0x8575d55f78b4751a  (0x6000009332f0) after it has been removed from its context.
>   CoreData: error: Mutating a managed object 0x8575d55f78b4751a  (0x6000009332f0) after it has been removed from its context.
>
> [error] error: Mutating a managed object 0x8575d55f7888751a  (0x60000096e940) after it has been removed from its context.
>   CoreData: error: Mutating a managed object 0x8575d55f7888751a  (0x60000096e940) after it has been removed from its context.

I do not find the impact by this error now, the APP is well and the CoreData is well. But I do not know whether it will impact my APP in the future. The second answer of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24965458/trying-to-save-nsmanagedobjectcontext-not-working/39048496) is like mine.

How to fix this error? Thanks for any help.